# Plot Z vs frequency for RLC circuit in CircuitLab

Tags: antenna, simulation, impedance, circuitlab

I am trying to simulate the resonance frequency of an antenna that can be modeled by a resistor in series with an inductor, both in parallel with a capacitor:

[image: Antenna Equivalent circuit]

By attaching the antenna to an AC current source and doing a frequench sweep, I want to:

- Plot impedance vs frequency
- Plot phase vs frequency

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM4jjA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using the frequency domain simulation:

[image]

I have plotted V vs frequency.

How do I now plot impedance vs frequency using CircuitLab?

[image]

Comment: I don't know about CircuitLab but I can plot Z = Vz / Iz in LTspice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *By attaching the antenna to a AC current source.....*

and

> *I have plotted V vs Freq.
> How do i now plot Impedance vs Freq using Circuitlab?*

So, set the current source to be 1 amp RMS and the resulting plot of voltage is transferrable 1:1 to impedance.

Comment: Thanks, not exactly a clean solution, but it does the job, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

How to plot it using Circuitlab, I do not know But I do know how to model it mathematically:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}&=\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\space{||}\space\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\cdot\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}+\text{R}\text{j}\omega\text{C}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\text{j}\omega\text{C}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\displaystyle1+\text{R}\text{j}\omega\text{C}+\text{j}^2\omega^2\text{CL}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\displaystyle1-\omega^2\text{CL}+\omega\text{CR}\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\displaystyle1-\omega^2\text{CL}+\omega\text{CR}\text{j}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1-\omega^2\text{CL}-\omega\text{CR}\text{j}}{\displaystyle1-\omega^2\text{CL}-\omega\text{CR}\text{j}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)\left(1-\omega^2\text{CL}-\omega\text{CR}\text{j}\right)}{\displaystyle\left(1-\omega^2\text{CL}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}
\end{alignat*}\tag1
$$

Where \$\alpha\space{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\$.

Comment: Thanks, 
I've already used this model with python to get the graphs out. I was interested now in being able to use circuitlab to match with my simulaiton.